# Make a simple Wordpress archive page

Tags: wordpress, archive

I want to create a simple Wordpress archive page exactly like on this website:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/archive/

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how will this solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too generic. If you want to create a page exactly like that, read tutorials and practice your html and css skills to achieve the output you want.

Comment: I am very proficient in HTML and CSS, I just need some php help.

Comment: check [this link](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_create_theme.htm).